# How do I access USB endpoints with recent Linux kernels?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, devices, usb-device

I am modifying some dated code (from year 2011; see [here](https://github.com/Geremia/licut/blob/master/licut_probe.cpp#L62)) that accesses a USB endpoint in the path:

> /sys/class/usb_endpoint/usbdevBUS.DEVICE_epENDPOINT/device

where "BUS", "DEVICE", and "ENDPOINT" vary.

However, my Linux setup (Slackware 14.2; kernel 4.4.14) doesn't have paths of this form.

How do I access USB endpoints with recent Linux kernels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are under `/sys/bus/usb`.

For example,

```
ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-0\:1.0/ep_81/

bEndpointAddress  bLength       direction  power  uevent
bInterval         bmAttributes  interval   type   wMaxPacketSize
```